# How to create an AsyncTask properly

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, osmdroid

I am new to Java and since this question belongs to a very time sensitive project for my work, I dont have the time to learn everything about AsyncTasks.
So my question is:

How do I construct an `AsyncTask`out of the following code?

The goal is to draw a route on a map. I fill the `ArrayList`with two `Geopoints` (start-location and the destination of the route). The `roadManager` is supposed to send those waypoints to a server that sends me back the route.

`buildRoadOverlay` is the method that finally draws the route on the map.

```
    RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(this);

    ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    GeoPoint myLocation = new GeoPoint(51.488978, 6.746994);
    waypoints.add(Location);
    waypoints.add(myLocation);
    Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
```

I guess this has to go in the `onPostExecute` -method, right?:

```
    Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road);
    map.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
```

The variable `location` from the upper code originates from a different method, from which I intend to start the Async task. Meaning, I need to transmit the variable to the AsyncTask when calling it, which I am also not sure how to do exactly.

This is the initialization of the variable `location`:

```
GeoPoint Location = new GeoPoint(Double.parseDouble(place.getLongitude()), 
    Double.parseDouble(place.getLatitude()));
```

Comment: Asynctask consists of onPreExecute(), doInBackground(), onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute().  You will show the progress bar within here.  You will set up/open your connection within the doInBackground(params...), where you perform your background tasks that will take long time.You can invoke publishProgress() here and it will be published on the onProgressUpdate() step, you must return a value here. At the onProgressUpdate() stage you will show the updates.  At the last stage, onPostExecute(your result), invoked on ui thread, you will get the result from your background task upon completion.

Comment: I am using osmdroid (OpenStreetMaps)

Comment: That it's irrelevant, you can use AsyncTask with anything, a download, appling image filter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the time consuming task in doInBackground(), udpate view in onPostExecute().

```
public void drawRouteAsync() {
    GeoPoint location = new GeoPoint(Double.parseDouble(place.getLongitude()),
            Double.parseDouble(place.getLatitude()));
    GeoPoint myLocation = new GeoPoint(51.488978, 6.746994);

    new RouteAsyncTask().execute(location, myLocation);
}

private class RouteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<GeoPoint, Void, Road> {
    @Override
    protected Road doInBackground(GeoPoint... params) {
        ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
        waypoints.add(params[0]); // location
        waypoints.add(params[1]); // myLocation
        RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(mContext); // your context
        Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints); // time consuming
        return road;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Road road) {
        Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road);
        map.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay); // update view
    }
}
```

Comment: cant test it right now because Android Studio tells me "OSRMRoadManager (android.content.Context) in OSRMRoadManager cannot be applied to bla.bla.bla.RouteAsyncTask" and underlines the "this"

Comment: Yea, you need to pass some object that work as Context. I mean activity or application context. In this answer `this` mean the asyncTask an it's not a context.

Comment: @MansApps Do you know how to do that? I dont even know what a context is. What exactly should I write in this brackets for this to work?

Comment: @Glave give it a context. If you are calling from an activity, getApplicationContext() will return the application context, just replace mContext with getApplicationContext().

Answer (score 1):

**AsyncTask** have 3 important methods:

1. `protected void onPreExecute()` //main thread
2. `protected E doInBackground(T... params)` //async thread
3. `protected void onPostExecute(E result)` //main thread

`E` and `T` will be definded in implementation.

---

So knowing this, your `AsincTask` should look somthing like this:

```
public class GetRouteTask extends AsyncTask<GeoPoint, Void, Integer> {

    private Context mContext;
    private OnGetRouteCompleted delegate;
    private Road route;

    public GetRouteTask (Context context, OnGetRouteCompleted delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(GeoPoint... params) {
        ArrayList<GeoPoint> wayPoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
        wayPoints.add(params[0]); // pointFrom 
        wayPoints.add(params[1]); // pointTo 

        try {
            RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(mContext);
            route = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
            return 1;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {
        if (success == 1) {
            delegate.onGetRouteCompleted(true, route);
        } else {
            delegate.onGetRouteCompleted(false, null);
        }
        Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road);
        map.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay); // update view
    }

    public interface OnGetRouteCompleted {
        public void onGetRouteCompleted(boolean success, Route route);
    }
}
```

And this how you use it:

```
public class SomeActivity extend Activity implements OnGetRouteCompleted {

    // Methods and properties...

    public void drawRouteAsync() {
        GeoPoint pointFrom = new GeoPoint(51.489878, 6.143294);
        GeoPoint pointTo = new GeoPoint(51.488978, 6.746994);

        new GetRouteTask(getApplicationContext(), this).execute(new GeoPoint(){pointFrom , pointTo});
    }

    @Override
    public void onGetRouteCompleted(boolean success, Route route) {
        if (success) {
            Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(route);
            map.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay); // update view
        }
    }
}
```